# Exception "Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)."

Tags: mysql, netbeans

```
query="INSERT INTO paint_inventory(ID,Name,type,gallons,quarters) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
con.prepareStatement(query);
pstm.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(itemID_newitem_field.getText()));
pstm.setString(2,name_newitem_field.getText());
pstm.setString(3,type_newitem_field.getText());
pstm.setInt(4,Integer.parseInt(gallons_quantity_newitem_field.getText()));
pstm.setInt(5,Integer.parseInt(quarters_quantity_newitem_field.getText()));
pstm.execute();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"item has been registered");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pstm` is defined in your code? Hope you need to assign the `prepareStatement` to the `pstm` then you can set the parameter values.

Also ensure the `pstm` is not used for another `prepareStatement` with in the same method or other methods. Each `prepareStatement` should have separate variable name to set the parameter values.

```
query="INSERT INTO paint_inventory(ID,Name,type,gallons,quarters) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
pstm = con.prepareStatement(query); -- assign to pstm then set values
...
...
```

Comment: thanks bro...i was using pstm for another preparestatement...now its working well....thanks alot bro

Comment: @nabeel If it solves your problem, you may accept the [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043)